# Mouse Unmoveable When Any Key Is Pressed Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, mouselistener

I am trying to make a simple game in which both the mouse and keys are used at the same time to control the character. The issue I am having is as soon as I hold down any key I am unable to move the mouse. Even when I release the key there is a small delay before I am able to move the mouse again. I thought this may be due to my use of key/mouse Listeners however I have made the simplest working program that displays this error:

```
package listenerproblem;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ListenerProblem extends JFrame{

    public ListenerProblem(){
        super("Problems");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100, 200);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setSize(100,200);
        jPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel.setFocusable(true);

        add(jPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListenerProblem listenerProblem = new ListenerProblem();
    }

}
```

I would just like to know what is causing this error and if there is any workaround within Swing so that both the mouse and keys may be used simultaneously.

If it is important in any way I am using a TOSHIBA C50-A-1E2 with Windows 8.1
and the program was made and run in NetBeans. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you running your UI-related code in the Event Dispatch Thread?

Comment: I believe so. I would create a class for a Key/Mouse Listener then do jPanel.addKeyListener(new myKeyListener());. However the problem of the mouse being stuck still occurs in this simple program without any listeners of any kind. If you run this do you have the mouse freeze on you please?

Comment: no, it doesn't freeze for me when pasting and running your code. Which JDK are you building with and which JRE are you running with?

Comment: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201) 
Java: 1.8.0_91; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b14 
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_91-b14. Any idea why this may be happening please?

Comment: Also, what I mean by freeze is; if you have the mouse above the window and press a key (such as the up key for my game) and hold it, can you still move the mouse please?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue as described. Not sure why it's happening. Try compiling from command line and running from their manually with differnet Java versions

Comment: Hi @Kon, I have just found the issue to my problem and posted a solution. I honestly expected you to be able to replicate my issues and that there was a problem with my code. Since you weren't able to I realized there must be an issue with my system and touch-pad, which there was. Without you informing me that you couldn't get the mouse to freeze I would have carried on thinking that there was something wrong with my Java code. Many thanks for taking the time to help me and enabling the issue to be resolved; it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that I ran this code on a laptop with a touch-pad. The settings on my computer were such that **it** stopped me from moving my mouse when typing and had nothing to do with the code. If you want to fix this problem on Windows, here is how:

1. Click 'Mouse' within the 'Control Panel' (this should give you a 'Mouse Properties' box)
2. Then Click on the rightmost tab which ought to be 'Device Settings'
3. Within that tab Click the 'Settings' button
4. This should open another window within which you want to Click on 'Pointing'
5. This then reveals an option named 'PalmCheck' which you should Double Click on (opening another window)
6. Finally put the slider all the way down to 'Minimum' and Click 'Close' on that window and 'OK' on the previous one

I realized that my issue must be related to my particular system when others tried to replicate my problem using the same code and could not. I would like to thank them for their help in resolving this issue for me.

.